# get the average equibrilium from an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

There are n elements in the array. I need to divide the array in two parts where average of both array parts is same.

Say, you have an array [1, 2, 3]. Here elements [1, 3] have average of 2 whereas element [2] too have an average of two.

Another example is that : [1, 2, 5, 4]. Here elements [1, 5] has an average of 3 whereas elements [2, 4] too have an average of 3.

So, in case there exists such an average condition, I should flag "Yes" otherwise "No". What data structure/algorithm would you recommend for such problem?

I tried something on lines of this :
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/equilibrium-index-of-an-array/
but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert of algorthms and the only solution I can think now is a bit brutal:

- avg(array)
- if there is an element with the same value of the avg => done
- sort of the array
- starting from the biggest element, I would calculate the avg with the others starting from the smallest ones with tail recursion (until they don't give a solution higher than the calculated avg or the calculated avg)
- if I find a combination which gives the calculated avg, the remain numbers will give the same avg for sure

Unluckily I don't remember any kind of useful theorem about the average...

Comment: Yes. This is what I have also thought.